# Load and call helper in library

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, helper

How do I call a helper within a library in Codeigniter?

My code:

```
class Upload
{
    protected $ci;  

    function __construct()
    {   
        $this->ci =& get_instance();    

        // Load helper
        $this->ci->load->helper('form');
    }


    function upload_file($file, $file_types = 'gif|jpg|png', $max_size = 1000, $max_width = 200, $max_height = 300)
    {
        // Set params
        $config['upload_path'] = 'attached-files';
        $config['allowed_types'] = $file_types;
        $config['max_size'] = $max_size;

        // Check if max_width is set equals to it is a image
        if(isset($max_width))
        {
            $config['max_width']    = $max_width;
            $config['max_height']   = $max_height;  
        }

        // Try to upload the file
        if (!$this->ci->upload->do_upload($file))
        {
            $data['profile_image_upload'] = array('error' => $this->ci->upload->display_errors());
        }
        else
        {
            $data['upload_data'] = $this->ci->upload->data();
        }

        return $data;
    }
```

Im trying to build a universal library which I call when I want to upload files, independet if it is a pdf, image or another file.

But I get error on the following code:

```
if (!$this->ci->upload->do_upload($file))
```

Error message:
**Call to undefined method Upload::do_upload()**

Answer (score 0):

If you loaded a helper, you should be able to call functions in that helper just like this:

```
do_upload($file);
```

So change the line:

```
if (!$this->ci->upload->do_upload($file))
```

To this:

```
if (!do_upload($file))
```

Comment: When I do that I get this error message: `Call to undefined function do_upload()`. Am I loading it wrong in the constructor?

Comment: Is the function do_upload in your form_helper?

Comment: @JohnSmith What happens if you move `$this->ci->load->helper('form');` down to the function `upload_file`? And is your helper functions? Helpers must be functions, not classes.

Comment: I get the same error message when moving it into the function `Call to undefined function do_upload()`. do_upload() is original part of the helper form in CI. So I have not made anything with it by myself. It is all standard. Any other suggestions?